# Flex: how to apply styles to text child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the following HTML snippet...

```
<div class="container">
  Hello, World!
</div>
```

... I want to achieve a layout like this...

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| x | Hello, World!                              | y |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

... using flexbox layout and without changing the HTML structure.

My SCSS looks something like this:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;

    &:before {
        content: 'x';
    }

    &:after {
        content: 'x';
    }
}
```

which nearly does the right thing, except that the text content is horizontally centered instead of flush left.

Normally I would simply apply `flex-grow: 1` to the content that I wish to have at full width, but in this case there simply is no content node.

So, how can I make the text content grow? Thanks!

Comment: you code is doing fine like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case like this, where the text is not wrapped in its own element, Flexbox create an anonymous wrapper, which one can't target using CSS.

One solution is to drop the `justify-content` and use [auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) instead, on the `::after` pseudo element, shown below, another is to position the first pseudo `::before` absolute.

*Note, as `flex-direction: row;` is the default, you can omit it.*

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container:before {
  content: 'x';
}

.container:after {
  content: 'x';
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hello, World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `margin-left: auto` on `:after` instead.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container:after {
  content: 'y';
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container:before {
  content: 'x';
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hello, World!
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I have to accept @LGSon's answer because it's a little bit more verbose. ;-)